# Set MetaData to video made from Custom Camera

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

Can anyone tell me how to set **`MetaData`** to video made from custom camera app made in android .I want to set `MetaData` before **recording** i.e. before `mediaRecorder.start();` I read about -

- [MediaMetadataEditor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataEditor.html)
- [MediaMetadata.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadata.Builder.html)

Also, there is a method [setMetaData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html#setMetadata(android.media.MediaMetadata)) .But there is no proper way anywhere on StackOverflow or in Android Documentation to write `MetaData`. Only possible ways are - `FFmpeg`or `Mp4Parser`. But, Why to use external heavy libraries if Android provides us such methods?